# GitHub workflows doesn't find a module

Tags: python, github-actions, alembic

I'm trying to configure tests in the GitHub workflows for my FastAPI application. My `alembic.ini` -file is located in `app` folder. The alembic ´env.py´ is located in `app/alembic`.

This is how I try to run migrations:

```
- name: Migrate
        env:
          DB_USER: postgres
          DB_HOST: localhost
          DB_PASSWORD: postgres
        working-directory: app/
        run: |
          alembic upgrade head
```

GitHub finds my `alembic.ini` file but the problem is, in `app/alembic/env.py` I have an import `from app.core.config` and that gives me an error:

```
File "alembic/env.py", line 13, in <module>
    from app.core.config import settings  # noqa: E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.core'
```

I've tried setting the directory in the `env.py` like this:

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname

sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))))
```

Without this, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -e .`?

Comment: @AllanChain No, I haven't. I use `poetry` to handle dependencies and I have a separate step for it: `run: poetry install --no-root`

Comment: Have you set the library path correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to remove the line `sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))))` and run the migrations like this: `PYTHONPATH=. alembic upgrade head`.